# is it possible to get the status of a previous pipeline execution on gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab-ci.yml that does some stuff, it is scheduled to run every 4 hours.
problem is the first stage is pulling an image from a repo that sometimes gets offline, the solution is to try again 30 minutes later.

how, in the gitlab-ci.yml, can I query the status of the previous pipeline execution to know if I should run or not?

(an other scheduler will be added to trigger 30 minutes after the regular execution, a variable will be set to indicate that it's the launch of a backup pipeline)

Thanks.

ps : to be clear, I want an execution of the gitlab-ci.yml to be able to check the previous execution of the gitlab-ci.yml

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`CI_JOB_STATUS`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) variable, which tells you what is the specific status of a job in your pipeline. It can be `success`, `failed`, or `cancelled`. You don't provide more details about your pipeline in the question, so it is a little difficult to explain how to use it in your specific pipeline.

Comment: ah well I'm not looking to look at the status of a job, but of a pipeline execution.

it is my understanding that you can have multiple jobs in a gitlab-ci.yml, running this file is called a "pipeline execution".

the CI_JOB_STATUS is only available in the current pipeline execution, it cannot be read in the next one.

Comment: I see... well, I don't know if you can do something like that. I would try another approach, by defining a project variable: `IMAGE_WAS_PULLED`, you can update that variable (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_level_variables.html#update-variable) when you get the image in your first step. And then, in your other pipeline, you can read it to validate if you need to rerun the first step or not.

Comment: that might be a good solution indeed, thanks, I'll try that